# Why Appodeal Flutter Plugin says "D/Appodeal(22704): Banner [Request Failed]: No ads in banner"

Tags: flutter, facebook-audience-network, appodeal

Banner Ads from Meta Audience Network not showing.

Verbose Log in Flutter console

```
D/Appodeal(22704): SDK [Response]: {"status":"error","message":"No ads in banner"}
D/Appodeal(22704): SDK [Response]: {"status":"error","message":"No ads in banner"}
D/Appodeal(22704): Banner [Request Failed]: No ads in banner
D/Appodeal(22704): Banner [Load Failed (soft)]: REQUEST ERROR (4)
D/Appodeal(22704): Banner [Notify Load Failed]
D/Appodeal(22704): a [VisibilityTracker]: onViewTrackingFinished
D/Appodeal(22704): Banner [Finished]: Mraid - eCPM: 0.00, precache: false, expTime: 0, id: VTYzO...
D/Appodeal(22704): SDK [Response]
```